# Can't access id of a model after saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to link to a nested model, however, the id seems to be nonexistent.

In this form, I have the following

```
<% @photos.persons.each do |ans| %>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
        </p>

        <p>
            <%= ans.text %>
        </p>

        <h5><em>
            <%= ans.commenter %> posted 
            <%= link_to "Persons", photo_person_path(photos_id: @photo.id, id: ans.id) %>

        </em></h5>

    </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

However, it seems ans has no id? I have created the model via a form_for but cannot access its id. this is my create action for persons

```
def create
        @person = @photo.persons.new(params[:person])
        if @person.anonymous == true
            @person.commenter = "Anonymous"
        else
            @person.commenter = current_user.username
        end
        if @person.save
            redirect_to photo(@photo)
        else
            redirect_to photos
        end
    end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I wonder, that Rails created 'persons' association instead of 'people'.

Comment: where does `@photo` come from and what exactly is the error you get?

Comment: @IharDrozdov Rails will pluralize person as people.

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"persons", :photo_id=>1, :id=>nil} (don't worry about the pluralization and stuff, i've changed the names so it's more readable)

Comment: @photo comes from photo = Photo.find(:photo_id)

Comment: if @person.save ??? Does this actually save the data?  Can you run the console using "rails c" and then try and access the id.  Likely it's not even saving.

Answer (score 0):

**1. "Persons"**

Although Rails will naturally pluralize `person` as `people`, what have you got your association set up as?

You should have this:

```
#app/models/photo.rb
Class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :persons, class_name: "Person"
end
```

---

**2. `.save`**

You're not creating the `@photo` object in your `create` method:

```
def create
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    @person = @photo.persons.new(person_params)

    if @person.anonymous == true
        @person.commenter = "Anonymous"
    else
        @person.commenter = current_user.username
    end
    if @person.save
        redirect_to photo(@photo)
    else
        redirect_to photos
    end
end

private

def person_params
   params.require(:photo).require(:params)
end
```

Could be more issues, but this what I found so far